# Git : Removing .gitignore file doesn't seem to have any affect

Tags: git, delete-file

Working in an existing directory that the only file is the .gitignore which looks like this :

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

After adding 2 new files and doing a "git status", the 2 new files don't appear due to the .gitignore file.

I figure the .gitignore needs to be removed. To do this, the following command was executed.

```
> git rm -f .gitignore
```

Doing a "git status", the 2 new files still don't appear.

Even tried this command afterward, but still the 2 new files don't appear with the git status" command.

```
> git add .gitignore
```

I have since tried to do a reset and all but that generated other issues. Even deleting the branch and recreating it didn't help. Eventually I had to do a "git reset --hard". This brought back the .gitignore file and my other files I created are still there. Essentially I am back to square 1.

What commands need to be executed so that a "git status" will show the newly created files?

Comment: That's weird. I cannot reproduce your problem. After `git rm -f .gitignore` the gitignore file is staged for deletion and I can see the two files again. What version of git are you using and have you checked if there is a file/file system sync problem?

Comment: git version 2.9.3

Comment: And after executing the git rm, and doing a "git status" shows  the files are now untracked files?

Comment: Yes. I add two new files, don't see anything, then I do a `git rm -f .gitignore` and see the gitignore staged for removal plus the two files as untracked.

Comment: Any chance there's a `.gitignore` file in a parent directory that might apply?

Comment: Just tried it again and although "git status" shows "deleted:    .gitignore", the other new files are not visible.

Comment: Traversing up the directory chain doing "ls -a" and I am not seeing any other .gitignore until I get to the project's base directory and there is not reference there.

Comment: Are you using "git status" only or with some extra option?

Comment: Recreated the files then did "git status" again and still not visible.

Comment: Going ahead and doing a "git add" on the file even though it does not appear may work as the "git status" shows "new file:"

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
git check-ignore -v
```

on the various files that Git is continuing not to complain-about, so as to see which *other* control file is telling Git *don't complain about these files*.

If that produces nothing, use `git ls-files -v` to look for index entries whose flag is either `h` or `S`, indicating that a file is marked `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree`, or `s` (both flags set).  It might also be worth checking with `-f` for "fsmonitor valid" flags in case there is a bug in that code.

Comment: Thanks. It is now working but will document these commands if the issue happens again.

Comment: I ran "git ls-files -v" in the directory and wondering since I did a "git rm" on the .gitignore file should it not have been listed with a 'R'?

Comment: @UnhandledException: No, because this form of `git ls-files` is *only* looking in the index. A file in the index is never removed: it's either there in the index, or not there in the index, and that has covered all possibilities.